# Multiple condition linq

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am using linq in my application. Query has several conditions `.Where(a => !one || a.id == 1)`.

```
bool one = false;
bool two = false;
bool three = false;

db.type.Where(w => !one|| w.id == 1).Where(w => !two || w.id == 2).Where(w => !three || w.id == 3).ToList()
```

But this query give me result:

```
db.type.Where(w => w.id == 1 &&
                  w.id == 2 &&
                  w.id == 3)
```

I want to get:

```
db.type.Where(w => w.id == 1 ||
                  w.id == 2 ||
                  w.id == 3)
```

Help me please. How I can this fix?

Comment: Chaining multiple `Where` is equivalent of single `Where` with `&&` of the criterias used. I guess you can see that you cannot simulate `||` with this technique.

Comment: @IvanStoev I can fix this using other technique?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample input and output data? Is there a relation between  variable `one` and id `1`?

Comment: Build single `Where` with `or` conditions. If it needs to be dynamic (which I guess is the case), then there are plenty of examples on SO, usually involving some sort of a predicate expression builder.

Comment: @RePierre Variable <code>one</code> is not relating to<code>id</code>, it needs for dynamically add condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to `or` the ids in your where predicate you can use [`Enumerable.Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method like this:

```
var ids = new[]{1, 2, 3};
db.type.Where(w => ids.Contains(w.id));
```

However, what I *assume* you want is a way to dynamically create the predicate for the `Where` clause and believe me, using flags with or conditions is not the way to do this; **not only the condition will make the other persons reading that code cry blood but it will also lead to bad query performance**. 
The proper way to do this is using a [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). Take a look at the article to see how it should be used and what it does.

There's a caveat to it however - it won't work in `Entity Framework` or `nHibernate`. To create one for the the above ORMs, use this blog post on [Universal predicate builder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/).

Comment: Thank you for help, I am using <code>Universal predicate builder</code> and the predicate class are giving result for me!