# complicated mvc linq generated sql script

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, .net-4.5

I am pretty new to MVC world, but I been doing asp.net for years now. I started this project with mvc so I can get used to it. I been struggling some overly complicated sql statements linq has been generating I think I am doing something wrong. Maybe its doing it correctly I just cant tell without writing the sql statement from scratch.

Ok the goal is to I got this identity db which I've added a few fields and also linked in some other tables like addresses and phoneNumbers and so on.

I am working on vendor search screen and wanted to use linq to get the data. Some of the info is on dropdowns for table1 in example below, and have a text search option that allows to "OR" search on multiple fields on main aspnetusers and some other tables.

I hope someone help me get a simplified version of this on linq. Or should I start writing my sql and use that in here somehow (no clue how to do that in mvc but should be pretty similar

```
 var VendorRole = await db.Roles.FirstAsync(r => r.Name == "vendor");

        var results = db.Users.Include(u => u.table1).
            Include(u => u.table2).Include(u => u.table3).
            Include(u => u.table4).Include(u => u.table5).
            Where(u => u.Roles.Any(s => s.RoleId == VendorRole.Id));

        if (id1.HasValue)
        {
            results.Where(m => m.table1.First(a => a.id1 == id1) != null);
        }

        if (id2.HasValue)
        {
            results.Where(m => m.table1.First(a => a.id2 == id2) != null);
        }

        if (id3.HasValue)
        {
            results.Where(m => m.table1.First(a => a.id3 == id3) != null);
        }

        IEnumerable<string> searchTerms = SearchString.Split(' ')
                                              .Select(x => x.Trim());
        foreach (string term in searchTerms)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(term))
            {
                string captured = term.ToUpper();
                results = results.Where(t => (t.field1.ToUpper().Contains(captured) ||
                                            t.field2.ToUpper().Contains(captured) ||
                                            t.field3.ToUpper().Contains(captured) ||
                                            (t.field2 + " " + t.field3).ToUpper().Contains(captured) ||
                                            t.field4.ToUpper().Contains(captured) ||
                                            t.field5.ToUpper().Contains(captured) ||
                                            t.table2.Any(m => (m.field6 + " " + m.field7).ToUpper().Contains(captured)) != null));
            }
        }


        ViewBag.count = results.Count();
        if ((page -1) * 10 > ViewBag.count)
        {
            page = (int)Math.Floor((double)ViewBag.count / 10);
        }
        ViewBag.page = page;
        return PartialView(await results.OrderBy(m => m.field1 + " " + m.field2 + " " + m.field3).Skip((page - 1) * 10).Take(10).ToListAsync());
```

Thank you for spending time to help.

Comment: Having multiple `Where` clauses is the equivalent of an `AND` operation not an `OR`. Do you really want to use `OR` on _all_ conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your query looks now, each `Where` clause is matched using `AND` on the collection, not `OR`.

If you really want to use `OR` for *all* conditions, the following should be useful.

As I mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36622878/844006), the proper way to build complex query predicates with `Linq` is the use of a [`PredicateBuilder`](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx). Having this in place you can refactor your code into two parts:

1. Building the predicate for the `Where` clause and
2. Querying the data

The code would look like this:

```
private Expression<Func<User, bool>> BuildIdQuery(
    Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate,
    int? id,
    Func<User, int> propertySelector)
{
    if(id.HasValue)
    {
        // First(...) with throw an exception if there are no items
        // matching the predicate; Any() is the proper way to do it.
        return predicate.Or(m => m.Any(a => propertySelector(a) == id);
    }
    return predicate;
}

Expression<Func<User, bool>> BuildSearchTermQuery(
    Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate, string searchTerm)
{
    if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm)
        return predicate;
    // You don't need to use ToUpper() unless you 
    // know that your database performs case-sensitive comparison
    return predicate.Or(m => m.field1.Contains(searchTerm))
        .Or(m => m.field2.Contains(searchTerm)); // etc.
}
```

Having all that the query would look like this:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<User>()
predicate = BuildIdQuery(predicate, id1, a => a.id1);
predicate = BuildIdQuery(predicate, id2, a => a.id2);
foreach(var term in searchTerms)
{
    predicate = BuildSearchTermQuery(predicate, term);
}

var results = db.Users
    .Where(predicate)
    .Skip(...)
    .Take(...);
```

Comment: Switched to using predicatebuilder, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you what to use Linq or stored procedure.
For text search in database you could look at [Lucene port](http://lucenenet.apache.org/)

I would recommend you to use N-tier to separate complex business logic from presentation. It will be easy for you to change/optimize it later.

```
/// <summary>
/// Assume you have special class to store users
/// </summary>
public class UserBdo
{
    public int id1 { get; set; }
    public int id2 { get; set; }
    ......
}

public class PagingParams
{
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
    public int PerPage { get; set; } = 10;
    /// <summary>
    /// How many without paging
    /// </summary>
    public int TotalResults { get; set; }
}

public class UsersBll
{
    public IEnumerable<UserBdo> Search(int? id1, int? id2, int? id3, IEnumerable<string> searchTerms, PagingParams pp)
    {
        var results = db.Users.Include(u => u.table1).
            Include(u => u.table2).Include(u => u.table3).
            Include(u => u.table4).Include(u => u.table5).
            Where(u => u.Roles.Any(s => s.RoleId == VendorRole.Id));

        if (id1.HasValue)
        {
            results.Where(m => m.table1.First(a => a.id1 == id1) != null);
        }

        if (id2.HasValue)
        {
            results.Where(m => m.table1.First(a => a.id2 == id2) != null);
        }

        //results = ...

        pp.TotalResults = 100;

        return results.Skip((pp.CurrentPage  - 1) * pp.PerPage).Take(pp.PerPage).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```