# How to filter results in Entity Framework with multiple select box

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have three tables for blog posts:

- `post_table` for posts properties like `post_id`, post_title and etc.
- `category_table` including of two columns such as `category_id` and category_name
- and `post_category_table` that is an interface table for relationship between `post_table` and `category_table` and it has two foreign key columns such as `post_id` and `category_id`.

Note that each post can have one or more categories.

[multiple select box (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEvRx.png)

Now I have an multiple select box (like attachment image) for categories that user be able to select one or more categories. When user select one or more categories from select box, results should be limited to selected categories.

How do I write "Where" condition for this problem with Entity Framework?

My code is:

```
var query = context.post_Table
    .Select(postinfo => new {
        post_title = postinfo.post_title,
        post_date = postinfo.post_date,
        post_id=postinfo.post_id,          
        post_category = postinfo.post_category_table.Select(cc => new {
            cc0=cc.category_id,
            cc1 = cc.category_table.category_name,
        }),

    }).Where(???)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get a collection of category ids from the multiple selection box (the ids of the selected categories).

Let's call that `selectedCategoryIds` and let's assume it's an `IEnumerable<int>`.

To filter the results according to the selected categories you'd do this:

```
var query = context.post_Table
    .Select(postinfo => new 
    {
        post_title = postinfo.post_title,
        post_date = postinfo.post_date,
        post_id=postinfo.post_id,          
        post_category = postinfo.post_category_table.Select(cc => new 
        {
            cc0 = cc.category_id,
            cc1 = cc.category_table.category_name,
        })
    })
    .Where(info => info.post_category.Any(c => selectedCategoryIds.Contains(c.cc0)));
```

**Edit**

If you have some conditional logic you can split and compose the query accordingly:

```
var query = context.post_Table
    .Select(postinfo => new 
    {
        post_title = postinfo.post_title,
        post_date = postinfo.post_date,
        post_id=postinfo.post_id,          
        post_category = postinfo.post_category_table.Select(cc => new 
        {
            cc0 = cc.category_id,
            cc1 = cc.category_table.category_name,
        })
    });

if(selectedCategoryIds != null && selectedCategoryIds.Any())
{
    query = query.Where(info => info.post_category.Any(c => selectedCategoryIds.Contains(c.cc0)));
}
```

However if your conditional logic is more complex than the trivial example above please take a look at [my answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36622878/844006) on why you should use a predicate builder.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but it returned error for `info.post_category.cc0`.

The error message is:

`IEnumerable<<anonymous type: int cc0, string cc1>>' does not contain a definition for 'cc0' and no extension method 'cc0' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: int cc0, string cc1>>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @msitworld, sorry for that; I didn't notice that `post_category` is a collection. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thank you very very much. it worked. thanks again. :)))

Comment: If `selectedCategoryIds` be null, results according to all categories should be returned, But when `selectedCategoryIds` is null occur an exception like this :
`Unable to create a null constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.`
Is it possible to help me?

Comment: @msitworld, I have edited the answer to provide more info on that.